# Turn plot around in R

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot, axes

Currently I am doing research to chatbot interfaces and make use of eyetracking to test my prototypes.

My eyetracking device creates a csv file with a x and a y coordinate every 16 mili seconds.

I want to plot this information with:

- The X-axis on the top
- The Y-axis on the right (starting with zero at the top)

Currently I have the following code:

```
dataleft = data[c(3,4)] 
dataleft_matrix = data.matrix(dataleft)
plot(dataleft_matrix, main="Eyetracking Left Eye", xlab="X-as", ylab="Y-as")`
```

However, this does not create the axes as I want them to be.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: it sounds like you want to flip axis.  You could try transposing your matrix. If you want more flexibility I would recommend using `ggplot2` package and the`coord_flip` function.

Comment: On the website it says that coord_flip changes vertical to horizontal, but that is not what I want...

Comment: Oh, I get it! See the answer of @jJakubg that's what you want.

Comment: I was wrong, you are right, I need ggplot2!

Comment: *"However, this does not create the axes as I want them to be..."* - You should probably state how they are, and how you would like them to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using ggplot for this, rather than base R. Of course, you may have good reason to prefer plotting using base R, but I find ggplot easier (and faster) to use.

```
library(ggplot2)
xleft <- c(2,3,4,2,1,2,3,4,5)
yleft <- c(2,3,4,3,2,1,6,5,3)
leftdata <- data.frame(xleft, yleft)
ggplot(data = leftdata) +
  geom_point(aes(x = xleft, y = yleft)) +
  scale_y_reverse(position = "right") +
  scale_x_continuous(position = "top") +
  ggtitle("Eyetracking Left Eye") +
  xlab("X-as") +
  ylab("Y-as")
```

[I think this is what you want it to look like, right?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4vgH.png)

Comment: And what must I do when the variables xleft and yleft are columns of an already existing dataframe?

Comment: You should use the same approach. The way that ggplot works, means that you first name your data frame e.g. ggplot(data = existingdataframe). Then you refer to the variable names in the geom_ e.g. x = xleft. I highly recommend you look at some examples of ggplot - it's a really excellent tool and is quick to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the direction of the y-axis in base R by adjusting the `ylim` parameter. To switch the location of the axes,  suppress the axes in the plot and then add them using the `axis` function.

```
plot(iris[,3:4], pch=20, ylim=c(2.5,0), 
     xaxt='n', yaxt='n', xlab="", ylab="")
axis(side=3)
axis(side=4)
```

[image: Adjusted axes]